# fosRestBundle : Send Array into Http Request Header

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle

**Aim :** Send an *Http request* as an **array** (i'm looking to the **uri syntax** if it's possible to send an array by the header of the **Http**)

***Server Side***

**ProfilHandler.php** My Profil Handler

```
/**
     * Get a list of News.
     *
     * @param int $limit  the limit of the result
     * @param int $offset starting from the offset
     * @param array $sector get profils by sectors
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function all($limit = 5, $offset = 0,$sector)
    {
        return $this->repository->findBy(array(), null, $limit, $offset, $sector);
    }
```

**ProfilController.php** My Profil Controller

```
/**
     * List all profiles.
     *
     * @ApiDoc(
     *   resource = true,
     *   statusCodes = {
     *     200 = "Returned when successful"
     *   }
     * )
     *
     * @Annotations\QueryParam(name="offset", requirements="\d+", nullable=true, description="Offset from which to start listing profiles.")
     * @Annotations\QueryParam(name="limit", requirements="\d+", default="10", description="How many pages to return.")
     * @Annotations\QueryParam(name="sector", requirements="\d+", default="IT", description="How many pages to return.")
    *
     * @Annotations\View(
     *  templateVar="profiles"
     * )
     *
     * @param Request               $request      the request object
     * @param ParamFetcherInterface $paramFetcher param fetcher service
     *
     * @return array
     */
    // ....
    public function getProfilsAction(Request $request, ParamFetcherInterface $paramFetcher)
    {
        $offset = $paramFetcher->get('offset');
        $offset = null == $offset ? 0 : $offset;
        $limit = $paramFetcher->get('limit');
        $secteur = $paramFetcher->get('sector');

        return $this->container->get('genius_profile.profil.handler')->all($limit, $offset,$sector);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. For example:

Construct url like this:
url ->  `http://your-app.dev/app_dev.php/some/route/?options[city]=1231&options[county]=3432`

then in controller for `some/route` action you can get

```
$arr = $request->get('options', array());
```

And then `$arr` should conatin:

```
Array
(
    [city] => 1231
    [county] => 3432
)
```

**[Edit]:**

Maybe try this:

Remove requirements for `sector` (or set it to match comma separeted list `requirements="[\w,]+"`:

```
* @Annotations\QueryParam(name="sector", default="IT", description="How many pages to return.")
```

Then construct url with `sector` as an comma separated list, for example

```
?offset=5&limit=10&sector=IT,HEALTH
```

And inside controller retrive it like this:

```
$secteur = explode(',', $paramFetcher->get('sector'));
```

**[Edit2]:**

```
public function all($limit = 5, $offset = 0,$secteur)     {
    if (sizeof($secteur)>=1){
        return $this->repository->findBy(array('secteur' => $secteur), array('secteur' => 'ASC'));
    }
    return $this->repository->findBy(array(), null, $limit);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. Why and where you need array?

Comment: Can't you just make a `?offset=5&limit=10&secteur=20` request?

Comment: @pazlux no .. i need to send sectors as array for example fetch profils by sectors equals IT,HEALTH !

Comment: Did you get an error? What is returned by `$paramFetcher->get('sector')`?

Comment: i got Unrecognized field: 0", with `public function all($limit = 5, $offset = 0,$secteur)
    {
        if (sizeof($secteur)>=1){
                return $this->repository->findBy($secteur,
                array('secteur' => 'ASC'));
        }
        return $this->repository->findBy(array(), null, $limit);
    }`

Comment: You need to pass `$secteur` in array to `findBy`. See second update of my answer.